# Karate API Testing Running Tests from Command Line

Tags: karate

I see this example

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags ~@ignore" -Dtest=AnimalsTest
```

How do i pass feature file name directly in command line.

Something like :

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--features=classpath:com/test/graphql/features/Scenario1.feature" -Dtest=com.graphql.ApiTest;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using a Java JUnit runner in this case, add a [`@CucumberOptions`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#cucumber-options) annotation to the JUnit class and that is the recommended way to do what you want.

```
@RunWith(Karate.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "classpath:com/test/graphql/features/Scenario1.feature")
public class AnimalsTest {
    
}
```

EDIT - Karate no longer uses annotations for running tests, use the Java `Runner` API: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#parallel-execution